# proper use of ajax success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why does my success function never runs?

### JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'calculation.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        data1: 2,
        data2: 3
    },
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

### PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["data1"])){
    $dataA = $_POST["data1"];
    $dataB = $_POST["data2"];
    if(dataA + dataB === 5){
        echo "success";
        $result = true; //I tried all 3 of these things which it seemed like others did but it still dosen't run.
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error in your console? For information, if you use `dataType: "json"`, your ajax wait a return in json.

Comment: You could also include an `error` callback function in your ajax statement.  Also, when you're debugging, it's a good practice to use console.log rather than an alert window.  If you receive an object back, it might alert `[Object object]` which isn't helpful.  If you did `console.log(result)`, you'd be able to see exactly what result is.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will keep that in mind later, but iCode4U's answer worked.

Comment: @Ozay34: Alternatively, just remove `dataType: "json",`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo json_encode("success");
```

You have set the data type to json so you have to return json.

Comment: but you're not even returning JSON.  and it's a function, so you need to wrap it parens

Comment: that worked, thanks for the fast reply, i will accept this answer when i can

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "calculation.php",
    data: sendData,
    success: function(data) {

        var announcement = JSON.parse(data).announcement;

        alert(announcement);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("AJAX error");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
//Response to be sent back as json object
$response = array(
    "announcement" => "This is where you put what you want to be returned."
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

I like to add the `announcement` part because if something with PHP goes wrong, a PHP error won't be displayed directly to the user.  JavaScript will fail when it tried to call `JSON.parse(data).announcement`.